# How do I use or create a variable of a private class in Java

Tags: java

I'm creating a Inventory system(doing this for fun) and I have chose to use the queues as my data structure in java.  I use a private class within a public class and when I'm trying to run it test the queue I can't declare a variable of the private class. Here's my code

the class that contains the private class

```
public class Customer
{//begining of class

    private class Custque //creating private class to use as node
   {
        private int    Trn; 
        private String Lname;
        private String Fname;
        private String Mname;
        private String Mstatus;
        private String DOB;
        private String Email;
        private String permanentadd;
        private String mailingadd;
        Custque Next;


          public  Custque()//default constructor
          {
            Trn=0;
            Lname="";
            Fname="";
            Mname="";
            Mstatus="";
            DOB="";
            Email="";
            permanentadd="";
            mailingadd="";
            this.Next= Next;

          }

          public Custque(int T, String Ln, String Fn,String Mn, String MS, String dob, String email, String PA, String MA)//primary constructor
          {
               Trn=T;
               Lname=Ln;
               Fname=Fn;
               Mname=Mn;
               Mstatus=MS;
               DOB=dob;
               Email=email;
               permanentadd=PA;
               mailingadd=MA;
           }

         public void setTrn(int T)//trn setter
         {
           this.Trn= T;

         }

         public int getTrn() // trn getter
         {
           return Trn; 
         }

        public void setLname(String Ln)
        {
          this.Lname=Ln;
        }

        public String getLname()
        {
         return Lname;
        }

        public void setFname(String Fn)
        {
         this.Fname=Fn;
        }

       public String getFname()
       {
        return Fname;
       }

       public void setMname(String Mn)
       {
        this.Mname=Mn;
       }

      public String getMname()
      {
         return Mname;
      }

      public void setMstatus(String Ms)
      {
        this.Mstatus=Ms;
      }

      public String getMstatus()
      {
       return Mstatus;
      }

     public void setDOB(String dob)
     {
      this.DOB=dob;
     }

      public String getDOB()
     {
       return DOB;
     }

     public void setEmail(String email)
     {
      this.Email=email;
     }

      public String getEmail()
      {
       return Email;
      }

       public void setpermanentadd(String PA)
       {
         this.permanentadd=PA;
       }

       public String getpermanentadd()
        {
          return permanentadd;
        }
       public void setMailingAdd(String MA)
       {
         this.mailingadd=MA;
       }

       public String getmailingAdd()
      {
       return mailingadd;
      }

 }// end of private class

 private Custque front;
 private Custque last;

 public void enqueue (int trn, String Ln, String Fn, String Mn, String MS,String dob,String email,String PA, String MA)
 {
     Custque que = new Custque();//  creating a variable for the queue is null
     if (que.equals(null))// testing if the queue is null
        System.out.println("An error has occur");

       que.setTrn(trn);
       que.setLname(Ln);
       que.setFname(Fn);
       que.setMname(Mn);
       que.setMstatus(MS);
       que.setDOB(dob);
       que.setEmail(email);
       que.setpermanentadd(PA);
       que.setMailingAdd(MA);

      if(front.equals(null))
        last=front=que;
      else
        last.Next = que; 

       last = que; 

 }// end of enqueue

 public Custque dequeue()
 {
     if (front.equals(null)) 
     {
         System.out.printf("Queue is Empty");
         return null;
     }

     Custque i;
     i=front;
     front = front.Next;

    return front ; 
 }// end of dequeue



 void display()
 {
      Custque d;
      if(front != null)
      {
         d=front;
         System.out.printf("" + d);
      }
 }


}//end of main class
```

my driver class

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class driver 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
        int t,i;
        String ln,fn,mn,ms,dob,email,pa,ma;
        Custque s;/* line of error*/

        for(i=0; i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
            t= num.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner l = new Scanner(System.in);
            ln = l.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner f = new Scanner(System.in);
            fn = f.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);
            mn = m.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner mar = new Scanner(System.in);
            ms = mar.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner d = new Scanner(System.in);
            dob = d.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
            email = e.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner per = new Scanner(System.in);
            pa = per.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("");
            Scanner mai = new Scanner(System.in);
            ma = mai.nextLine();


        }// end of loop

}

}//end of driver
```

Comment: Why are you using a "private" inner class? What is your motivation behind this requirement?

Comment: A suggestion.  Constructors with long lists of parameters (like Custque) are hard to use and can be difficult to maintain.  This class is an excellent candidate for the *Builder Pattern*.  Using this pattern would make your class easier to use and it would make your code easier to read and to maintain.

Comment: Another suggestion.  Though they are not strictly required by the compiler, Java nevertheless has official *coding style requirements*.  Following them makes your code easier for others to understand.  For example, class members (such as methods and instance fields) and local variables should **never** begin with a capital letter.

Comment: Ok I understand using Queues and stacks linked list implementation in C++. The way I've learn it was to use header files however Java doesnt support that. What I'm basically trying to achieve is to understand how to use queues and stacks in Java

Answer (score 1):

A private inner class means that you can only access inside the outer class, in this case Customer.
In fact, if you are declaring a private inner class yourself are saying: "I want to nobody can see this class". So you are going against your one code.

But, like @Hovercraft Full Of Eels says, what is the requiremnt behind this. Maybe we can help more. Or it's only a doubt about the java semantics?